# PostgreSQL: How to combine multiple columns from 2 tables?

Tags: postgresql

I am very new to PostgreSQL and I can't combine two tables.

I have the table `title` and table `movie_info`. In both tables I have the column `id`.

From the table `title` I want the column `kind_id` where `kind_id = 6` and from the table `movie_info` I want the column `info` where `info = Netherlands` and the column `info-id` where `info_type_id = 8`.

```
SELECT mi.id, mi.info_type_id, mi.info, t.kind_id 
FROM title t 
  JOIN movie_info mi ON mi.id = t.id
WHERE t.kind_id = 6
```

How to combine above with this

```
and where mi.info_type_id = 8
and mi.info = 'Netherlands'
```

Can someone please help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are not so far, try this :

```
SELECT mi.id, mi.info_type_id, mi.info, t.kind_id 
 FROM title t 
 JOIN movie_info mi
   ON mi.id = t.id
WHERE t.kind_id = 6
  AND mi.info = 'Netherlands'
  AND mi.info_type_id = 8
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I've already tried what you say. But then I get empty columns back?

Comment: if 'empty columns back' means no row as a result, then there is just no data in both tables that matches the 3 filtering criteria, but it does not mean that the query doesn't work.

Comment: It's an assignment I have to do for school, so it seemed odd to me if nothing came out. But who knows, the teacher is really that crazy ;-) Thanks for your help!

Comment: Post your table definitions (ddl) and a small set of test data, and the expected results of that data,  all as text  - **no images**.  A commonly used technique is to define a column `id` as a primary key and automatically generate its value. If both your tables do this it would be **extremely rare** for both tables to have the same id; perhaps it is your `on` condition that is eliminating all the rows.

Comment: Thanks Belayer! You're right. The 'on' condition was indeed incorrect. I have now looked again at the id columns and it should be mi.info_id = t.id instead of mi.id = t.id. Now that I have changed this, I get a result :-)